# How to flag all records for a date when at least two records for that date have same duration OR at least one record has 0 durtation

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to flag records for a date when there are the same duration or at least one of the records have 0 duration.  CODE SH is the duration being matched to or if another records has a 0 duration.  Example Records being analyzed:

| Date | Code | Duration |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4/2/23 | AB | 510 |
| 4/2/23 | SH | 510 |
| 4/2/23 | B2 | 15 |

**also with 0**

| Date | Code | Duration |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4/2/23 | AB | 0 |
| 4/2/23 | SH | 510 |
| 4/2/23 | B2 | 15 |

**Expect this:**

| Date | Code | Duration | FLAG |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4/2/23 | AB | 510 | Y |
| 4/2/23 | SH | 510 | Y |
| 4/2/23 | B2 | 15 | Y |

OR

| Date | Code | Duration | FLAG |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4/2/23 | AB | 0 | Y |
| 4/2/23 | SH | 510 | Y |
| 4/2/23 | B2 | 15 | Y |

I was going to do an analytic function that counted records using code and date as partition.

`count(1) over (partition by date,code,duration)`

but then realized how do I handle 0's as well ?  Thanks for any help.

Comment: So, in the first example all 4/2/23 rows get a 'Y', because SH=510 and there is another row with 510? And in the second example all 4/2/23 rows get a 'Y', because SH=510 and there is another row with 0?

Comment: Yes, that is correct

Comment: I've corrected the tags, because it seems you are looking for a SQL query (`sql`), not a PL/SQL function (`plsql`). PL/SQL is a programming language you don't need here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use count and min window functions as the following:

```
with t as 
(
  select tb.*,
      count(*)  over  (partition by date_, code, Duration) cnt,
      min(Duration) over (partition by date_, code) min_dur
  from tbl tb
) 
select t.date_, t.code, t.duration,
  case 
    when min_dur = 0 or -- there is a 0 duration
         max(cnt) over (partition by date_, code) > 1 -- when there are the same durations in multiple rows. 
    then 'Y' else 'N'
  end as flg
from t
```

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/gPFKJ8Q0)

Answer (score 1):

I am a bit tired, so there might be a much simpler method that I fail to see right now, but you can just intersect date/duration for SH and non-SH and then add the dates with a zero duration.

```
select date, code, duration
from mytable
where date in
(
  select date from
  (
    select date, duration
    from mytable
    where code = 'SH'
    intersect
    select date, duration
    from mytable
    where code <> 'SH'
    union all
    select date, duration
    from mytable
    where duration = 0
  )
);
```

or

```
select date, code, duration
from mytable t
where exists
(
  select date, duration
  from mytable t2
  where t2.date = t.date and t2.code = 'SH'
  intersect
  select date, duration
  from mytable t3
  where t3.date = t.date and t3.code <> 'SH'
)
or date in
(
  select date
  from mytable
  where duration = 0
);
```

Answer (score 1):

ahmed's tip help get me what I needed.  I had to tweak it a bit but it worked.  I actually needed one more partitioned field as well for emp id.  Here's what I came up with:

This cte finds the max duration which is not SH and min duration.

```
,t as 
(
  select tb.*,
      max(case when code <> 'SH' then duration end)  over  (partition by nom_date, emp_id) mx,
      min(Duration) over (partition by nom_date,emp_id) min_dur
  from scd tb
)
```

This flags records I do not need:

```
select 
to_char(nom_date,'MM-YYYY')Mnth,
nom_date,
EMP_ID,
from
(
select t.nom_date,t.emp_id, t.code, t.duration,
  case 
    when min_dur = 0 or -- there is a 0 duration
         max(case when code = 'SH' THEN duration end) over (partition by nom_date,emp_id) = max(mx) over (partition by nom_date,emp_id) -- when there are the same durations in multiple rows. 
    then 'Y' else 'N'
  end as flg
from t
)
where FLG = 'N' and CODE = 'SH'
```

Comment: Hello! This is your first answer, thank you for sharing, keep going! There is a space for improvement, your code looks poorly formatted and probably not working (no space between a right bracket and and an alias, I think this could be an error). There is good rule to show code of high enough quality. Could you be so kind and improve it a bit?

Comment: Follow the Gerard's comment to improve the response